# How to use merge in SQL to meet certain conditions?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have TBL_B which contains these columns:

```
DROP TABLE TBL_B;
CREATE TABLE TBL_B (
PERSON_IDENFITICATION VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
TRANSACTION_IDENTIFICATION VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
LAST_STATUS VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
BOUGHT_DATETIME DATETIME NOT NULL,
CLAIMED_DATETIME DATETIME NOT NULL,
RETURNED_DATETIME DATETIME NOT NULL,
EXPIRATION_DATETIME DATETIME NOT NULL
);
```

I have TBL_1 which ROUND 1 Looks like this:

[image]

ROUND 2 Looks like this:
[image]

The STATUS always follows this order: BOUGHT > CLAIMED > RETURNED. You might not have all the status for each transaction, but it will always follow this order.

In the merge function, I would like to insert a record if a status found coming from TBL_1 in ROUND 2 (the following table) is GREATER than what had been previously updated. For example, transaction '222' did not have 'RETURNED' status previously, now, it was been added. I want this record to be inserted. For Transaction '111', ROUND 1 had 'RETURNED', now it doesn't. I do not want this record to be updated.

I have this query so far, but I'm having trouble inputing the exact conditions to only update if the last status in Round 2 is greater has been updated.

```
MERGE INTO TBL_B B
USING (
SELECT    
PERSON_IDENFITICATION,
TRANSACTION_IDENTIFICATION
,(array_agg(STATUS) within group(order by STATUS_DATETIME desc)[0])::varchar as LAST_STATUS
,coalesce(max(case when STATUS = 'BOUGHT' THEN STATUS_DATETIME END), max(case when STATUS = 'CLAIMED' THEN STATUS_DATETIME END), max(case when STATUS = 'RETURNED' THEN STATUS_DATETIME END), '1900-01-01'::datetime) as BOUGHT_DATETIME
,coalesce(max(case when STATUS = 'CLAIMED' THEN STATUS_DATETIME END),'1900-01-01'::datetime) as CLAIMED_DATETIME
,coalesce(max(case when STATUS = 'RETURNED' THEN STATUS_DATETIME END),'1900-01-01'::datetime) as RETURNED_DATETIME
,EXPIRATION_DATETIME
FROM TBL_1
GROUP BY 1,2,7
 ) A ON (A.PERSON_IDENTIFICATION = B.PERSON_IDENTIFICATION
   and A.TRANSACTION_IDENTIFICATION = B.TRANSACTION_IDENTIFICATION)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add conditions after MATCHED. For example

```
WHEN MATCHED AND A.RETURNED_DATETIME > B.RETURNED_DATETIME THEN
```